# Adding styles to PHP Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I need to add styles to this php code in Wordpress. How would I do this, everything I have tried to date hasn't worked.

```
<?php echo the_field('section_text'); ?>
```

This is the code I currently have.

```
<div id="inner-content" class="wrap cf">
    <p class="quote-text" style="font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif; font-size: 1.5em; line-height: 30px; text-align:justify; color:#664422; font-weight:bold; "><?php echo the_field('section_text'); ?></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you give a little more information? What have you tried so far? What is actually happening with your code?

Comment: Where does the field echo? Does it echo into a paragraph or div that can be styled?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're using the ACF plugin. You should not use `echo` while using `the_field()`.
Try this code.

```
<div id="inner-content" class="wrap cf">
    <p class="quote-text"><?php echo get_the_field('section_text'); ?></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all , you donot need to echo  `the_field`.  So the correct code can be

```
<?php the_field('section_text'); ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo get_field('section_text'); ?>
```

Now, I am guessing that the field named 'section_text' is an text editor field and its output is containing html codes like paragraph. Then change your code to this.

```
<div id="inner-content" class="wrap cf">
    <div class="quote-text"><?php echo get_field('section_text'); ?></div>
</div>
```

Now add the following css to your themes styles.css

```
.quote-text p , .quote-text * {
      font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif; 
      font-size: 1.5em; 
      line-height: 30px; 
      text-align:justify; 
      color:#664422; 
      font-weight:bold; 
}
```

Let me know if that works.